# How to load javascript asynchronously when using Sprockets and Turbolinks in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprockets, turbolinks

I want to include [zxcvbn.js](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) to my project and implement a password strength meter to go with my devise_zxcvbn gem.

However, I don't want to load `zxcvbn.js` through Sprockets.

So how do I load it asynchronously instead and run some codes after it loads, during `page:load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update with callback

I would probably use a getScript call, to avoid sprockets.  Just some coffeescript that checks for a valid devise registration url, or a modal, depending on your set up, then add:

```
$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  ZxcvbnWithTurbolinks

ZxcvbnWithTurbolinks =
  $.getScript('/js/zxcvbn.js').done((s, Status) ->
    console.warn Status
    # Do some other interesting stuff, like using the script you just fetched
    return
  ).fail (jqxhr, settings, exception) ->
    console.warn 'Something is hinky - not possible to check password strength' + exception
    return
```

Comment: How do I know if it is loaded so that I can implement a password strength bar afterwards?